# Executing seleneses in a new window does not work

Tags: selenium-ide

I am trying to execute selenese in a new window, but it seems that it doesn't work.
The simple test: open a new window, select it and click something there:

```
openWindowAndWait | http://cnn.com | cnn

selectWindow | cnn | |

click | link=Regions | |
```

The test fails and I don't know what I am missing - the click (the final command) is not executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it SHOULD work if you do this:

```
<tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td>name=cnn</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

By specifying name=cnn (instead of just cnn) but for me, I get an error:

> [error] Window does not exist. If this looks like a Selenium bug, make sure to read http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#alerts-popups-and-multiple-windows for potential workarounds.

but it defaults to the title of the page and as such this works for me:

```
<tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td>Breaking News, Daily News and Videos - CNN.com</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint!. Nevertheless with it, I get: [error] Element link=Regions not found, if I use "openWindow" and if I use "openWindowAndWait", I get: [error] Timed out after 30000ms. For some reason the command "selectWindow" is still not selecting the window "cnn"

Comment: That would indicate that you either don't have the right title and selenium is timing out while waiting for the right title or the URL you're loading is timing out upon page load. Try with a differnt URL.

Comment: Everything worked when used waitForPopUp before selectWindow. Thanks for the help.